# FSUIPC SDK installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, sdk

I have FSUIPC (with Prepar3D) and I want to create a program to get the Prepar3D's information through FSUIPC.

To do this, I want use Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 (or Visual Studio 2013) and the FSUIPC SDK.
The problem is that I don't usually use Microsoft Visual C++ and I don't know how to integrate the SDK.

I have .h .c .lib and .rc files but I don't really know what to do with...

Can anyone help me please?

Ben